# How do I add a List<Obect2> to List<Object1> in a C# foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I have a list that I am populating with some Json from a web service. I am able to populate the displayRecords with the code below. However I am having trouble getting the text field to populate with the text field. Each displayRecord can have 1 to n texts.

```
List<DisplayRecord> displayRecords = new List<DisplayRecord>();
foreach (var displays in ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords)
{
    displayRecords.Add(new DisplayRecord
    {
        displayDate = displays.displayDate,
        odometer = displays.odometer,
        type = displays.type                       
    });

    foreach(var texts in ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords)
    {
        texts.text = displays.text;
    }
}
```

This is the DisplayRecord Class

```
public class DisplayRecord
{
    public string displayDate { get; set; }
    public string odometer { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> text { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit for some clarity** The text fields never get the values from the second loop. They are all showing Null.

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Isn't the inner loop trying to assign a string to a List<string>?

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez No, `texts` and `displays` are of type `DisplayRecord`, so both are `List<string>`. The problem is that OP is iterating through the same list twice and assinging each element of the list' `text` property for the `text` property of every element of the same list.

Comment: why not `displayRecords.AddRange(ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords) `?

Comment: When you create a new DisplayRecord, can't you set it's text property to displays.text? And remove the second loop

Comment: @DanPantry I updated the original post to show what isn't working.

Comment: @Magnetron I know that you are probably right but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax but wanted to include both loops in what I posted here.

Comment: @BuckHicks Felipe answer bellow should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a `string`, when the constructor "asks" for a `List<string>`, I think this will work:

```
List<DisplayRecord> displayRecords = new List<DisplayRecord>();
foreach (var displays in ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords)
{
    displayRecords.Add(new DisplayRecord
    {
        displayDate = displays.displayDate,
        odometer = displays.odometer,
        type = displays.type,                       
        text = displays.text;
    });
}
```

Comment: OP is not assing a string to a List<string>, as my comment in the question states. But your code is correct, So, just correct the first line.

Comment: @Felipe Gutierrez I originally wrote it exactly like that but I didn't even try and run it because it didn't and still doesn't make sense to me that multiple texts values get added to what seems to be a one for one assignment. Anyway it does work so thanks. Does it work because public List<string> text { get; set; } just accepts the multiple text records as a List?

Comment: @BuckHicks yes, you are setting a List<string>

Comment: @BuckHicks it works because you're assigning a `List<string>` to a `List<string>`, why it shouldn't work? It's the same type. Just be aware that `List` is a reference type, so you're not copying the List, but pointing them both to the same object. If you modify one list the other will be modified too.

Answer (score 0):

### I see a few problems.

If you are trying to populate the DisplayRecord class's text property you would have to add it to the list and not try to set it to a string directly.

Since I don't know if `ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords.text` is a list or not I put in both solutions below:

You would need to do something like this:

```
List<DisplayRecord> displayRecords = new List<DisplayRecord>();
foreach (var displays in ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords)
{
    var displayRecord = new DisplayRecord
    {
        displayDate = displays.displayDate,
        odometer = displays.odometer,
        type = displays.type                       
    }

    displayRecord.text.AddRange(displays.text);

    displayRecords.Add(displayRecord);
}
```

AddRange() will take a List and inserts it into the variable text.

If you are wanting to add a single string to a list use Add() instead.

```
List<DisplayRecord> displayRecords = new List<DisplayRecord>();
foreach (var displays in ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords)
{
    var displayRecord = new DisplayRecord
    {
        displayDate = displays.displayDate,
        odometer = displays.odometer,
        type = displays.type                       
    }

    displayRecord.text.Add(displays.text);

    displayRecords.Add(displayRecord);
}
```

**Warning**

If you there is a uninstantiatedList (says null instead of Count=0) then when you try to add or access it, it would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you want you want:

```
var displayRecords = ro.serviceHistory.displayRecords
  .Select(r=>new DisplayRecord
    {
      displayDate = r.displayDate,
      odometer = r.odometer,
      type = r.type,
      text = r.text
    }).ToList();
```